# If loop in tkinter - button pressed

Tags: if-statement, button, tkinter

How to get tkinter to enter the if loop when button pressed to print? I do not want the print command to be in the button function.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Player:
   N = 0
   def __init__(self, name, points):
    # instance variables goes here
    self.name = name
    self.score = points
    # increment class variable
    Player.N = Player.N+1

class G_501:

  def __init__(self, players=[]):
    self.NoPlayers = len(players)
    print("Number of players",self.NoPlayers)
    Spillere = []
    Score = []
    Runde = 0


    for i in range(0, len(players)):
        P = Player(players[i], 501)
        print("Player", Player.N, P.name, "- Point:", P.score)
        Spillere.append(P.name)
        Score.append(P.score)
        Score = list(map(int, Score))


    root = Tk()
    c = [False]

    def half_bull(c, event=None):
        c.append(True)
        return c

    b1 = Button(root, text="Half Bull", bg="green", fg="black", command=lambda c=c: half_bull(c))
    b1.pack()

    print(c)
    if c[-1] == True:
        print("Fedt")

    root.mainloop()

S = G_501(["Chr"])
```

Only need help with the `tkinter` part... Thanks!

Comment: If you want something to happen after a button click, you put it into button's method. That's how it works. No idea why you don't want it to be in your method. This feels like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so it'd be better if you elaborate more on your problem.

Comment: your `if` is executed only once - at the start of script (and before you click button) - so you have to put it inside function which is executed by `command=`.